# Where can I find the Gryffindor Common Room in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I'm always struggling to remember where the Gryffindor Common Room is located and I find myself just aimlessly running around and trying to find it.

Where exactly is it? Does someone have easy directions to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gryffindor Common Room entrance in Hogwarts Legacy is hidden behind a portrait of the Fat Lady:

[image: The Gryffindor Common Room entrance in Hogwarts Legacy (Fat lady Portrait)]

To find it, you need to reach the Faculty Tower and head down the hall towards the winding staircase in the corner of the room. Then climb the staircase up toward the south wing of the Tower and search for the Fat Lady portrait:

[image: The Gryffindor Common Room entrance in Hogwarts Legacy (Fat lady Portrait)]

The portrait will allow you to pass if you are a Gryffindor student. Crawl through the small hole to enter the common room:

[image: The Gryffindor Common Room entrance in Hogwarts Legacy Hole in the wall]